# XSD parsing to XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to generate XML from this XSD schema. I am using the following tool for that: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation

schema location: FidelioXML.xsd

targetNamespace: V8XMLInterface

I get the following error: Not well formed: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your effort.

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="V8XMLInterface" />
<xs:element name="fidelio" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="FidelioXML.xsd">
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>The root element of any XML accepted by V8 XML Interface
   </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="request">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="update">
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="UserName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Vendor" type="xs:string" use="optional">
         <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Required when one of the licenses
           CRSXMLONEWAY_NCM, CRSXMLTWOWAY_NCM, CRSXMLONEWAY_FIDELIO8 or ftCRSXMLTWOWAY_FIDELIO8 is used
          </xs:documentation>
         </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
       </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="response">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Status codes are:
       OK Command or request successful
       CO Posting denied because overwrite CreditLimit is not allowed
       IA Guest related requests Invalid account
       NG Guest not found
       NP Posting denied because NoPost is set
       UR Unprocessable request, this request cannot be carried out, no retry
       IR Invalid request or unsupported request type
       IC Invalid credentials. Wrong username or password
       AD Access denied. Not enough user rights or trying to make batch update when it is not allowed be configuration
       Message is optional attribute used when Status is not OK
      </xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:choice>
   <xs:attribute name="Version" use="required">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>Specifies the version of the interface. Could be changed and in the future accept more values
     </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.0"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.2"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.3"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.4"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.5"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.6"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.7"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="1.1.0"/>
     </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:attribute> 
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your root element `xs:schema` is closed: `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="V8XMLInterface" />`. If you remove `/`, your XML becomes well-formed. The service you use also does not like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` for some reason, but it's actually OK.

Comment: Use an editor which supports XML syntax, it would have given you a hint on what's wrong.

Comment: Oh great thanks for the comment. Cannot believe I haven't seen it. And thanks for the hint with editor!